# Is there a more complete baseball Leverage table?

Tags: baseball, statistics, sabermetrics

I am interested in doing some baseball analysis with Leverage.

I found [Tom Tango's Leverage table](http://www.insidethebook.com/li.shtml) from The Book as well as Baseball-Reference's data pages (e.g., [this pitching page](http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/HOU/1978-pitching.shtml)).  However I noticed that The Book indicated values of 1.5 falling in both the medium-Leverage and high-Leverage categories.

Realizing this may be due to rounding, I have interest in finding a higher precision table (to two or more decimal places).  I'd also be interested in a table which covers additional situations in which a team leads by more than 4 runs. So does a more complete/precise table exist?

Comment: Unwrapping the details of your question, seems like you're saying the only real issue is that The Book table has 1.5 labeled both ways?  I don't know anything about this specific topic, but could it be a formula that is being calculate and rounded (such that 1.48 shows as 1.5 in grey and 1.52 shows as 1.5 in blue)?  It seems Baseball-Reference just uses the 0.7 and 1.5 which matches what the table (except it's inconsistency).

Comment: You should make these into two separate questions though to make it more approachable (and fit the SE format)... one about the apparent inconsistency on The Book table, the other asking whether a wider, more detailed table exists.

Comment: In regards to the inconsistency, I also would guess that it is the result of rounding; hence, I'm wondering if there's a table that goes to 2 decimal places, which would fix that problem. Really, my interest is in a "better" version of the table, whatever form that may take.

Comment: Pete, I tried to help focus the question down, as it was a tough question to slog through with all the details at first, and want to help you get what you are looking for.  Does the edit better do that for you?

Comment: Leverage is a pretty subjective quantity.  Having it expressed to 2 or more decimal places seems rather useless to me. Are you sure anyone actually believes 2.24 and 2.27 are really different?

Comment: @john the reason why I'd like the 2 decimal places is to deal with some inconsistency in the linked table. Due to rounding, you will see that 1.5 is listed as both medium and high leverage. My interest is in parsing out low, medium, and high leverage situations, and issues like this (in addition to the table only covering -4 <= homeScore - roadScore <= 4) are causing me problems.